# Title of questions in MS Teams notification abbreviated?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

We use MS Teams and have enabled notifications in various channels.

Unfortunately the title of a question in the notification is abbreviated after roughly 35 characters so you can rarely read the whole title. So if someone doesn't repeat the title in the description it is sometimes hard to understand what the actual question was just by reading the notification in MS Teams.

Can this be adjusted? Is it planned to improve this? If it is an MS Teams restriction, what about just repeating the full title in the body of the notification?

Most annoying is that the notification doesn't use the full width, why is this the case?
[image]

Comment: What happens if you hover the mouse over the title (presuming a desktop system)? Does it display the title?

Comment: No nothing happens, I tried it both with the web version in Chrome as well as with the desktop client of MS Teams. And I think it is not a restriction by MS Teams, other bots/notification like from GitLab use the whole width.

Comment: If I take a look at https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA200000739?tab=Overview, especially the demo pictures, it should have been worked better in the past, so I consider this a [bug] now.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, that dialogue is 100% configurable on our end so I've marked this as a feature request. I've added it to our internal tracker for consideration in the future.